# Not recognising whitespace as char in loop?

Tags: c, whitespace, fgets

I am reading text from a file and determining if the string begins with a `#` (excluding white space)
and if there is no other char (excluding white space) preceding the `#` I write it to a separate file.
We are supposed to preserve the whitespace in the string.
If there is white space before the `#` however it is not writing it. I am not sure if this is an `fgets` issue that
I am unaware of or another issue.

I am sure my algorithm is a bit clumsy

```
int valid = 1;

while(fgets(str, 250,f1)!=NULL)
{
    printf("read strings: %s",str);/*my test*/

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='#')
        {
            printf("strings: %s",str);/*my test*/
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(isspace(str[j])!=0)
                {
                    valid=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            valid=0;
        }
    }
    if(valid==1)
    {
        fprintf(f2, str);
    }
    valid=1;
}
```

So from file:

```
#the cat sat on# the mat  
the sunny day  
    #cats sit on mats
```

it will write:

```
#the cat sat on# the mat
```

*I have an exam next week and trying to get the best
 possible understanding I can in the short time I have left.*

Comment: I don't undertand the goal of the problem. What to yo mean with the "it" in "write it"? Is "it" the character "#" or "it" refers to the "line" containing "#"? Do you have to write every character in the line containing the "#" or well only those characters to the right of "#" in the line? What happens with a line as "abcd#hello"? What must be the output in this case? And what happens with lines not containing "#"? And what happens with an example like this: "12 #34#56"?

Comment: Aside: Please don't use `fprintf` like that: `fprintf(f2, str)` or you might get a nasty surprise if there are any `%` signs in your string. Prefer literal format strings: `fprintf(f2, "%s", str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first character is a space it will go into this else:

```
    if(str[i]=='#')
    {
       <snip>
    }
    else
    {
        valid=0;  // This line is executed if str[0] is space
    }
```

A better approach would be to skip until you find the first non-space character and if it is a '#' then print the line else don't print it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post my answer, as I had mucked up the test for `isspace` also. I reversed the value for `valid` and removed the offending `else`.

```
int valid = 0;

while(fgets(str, 250,f1)!=NULL)
{
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='#')
        {
            valid=1;
            printf("strings: %s",str);/*my test*/
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                if(isspace(str[j])==0)
                {
                    valid=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valid==1)
    {
        printf("saved strings: %s",str);
        fprintf(f2,"%s", str);
    }
    valid=0;
}
```

So the read file:

```
#the cat sat on# the mat
the sunny day
    #cats sit on mats
howdy hoo
h#hi there all
#hello jelly beans!#
#no
```

writes to file f2:

```
#the cat sat on# the mat
    #cats sit on mats
#hello jelly beans!#
#no
```

*thanks to Klas Lindbäck and M Oehm*